# Are the words "snowy", "icy", and "rainy" used differently than the words "sunny" and "cloudy"?

Tags: word-usage

When we say "It's sunny" and "It's cloudy", we're talking about the weather on a particular day or a particular time of the day, but in the dictionary, the other three words are defined as follows:

1. rainy: If it is rainy, it is raining a lot.

Therefore, I think we can't say "It's rainy" to talk about the weather. For that purpose, I think we should say "It's raining", but we can use it as an adjective and talk about "the rainy season".

2. snowy: Something that is snowy has a lot of snow.

Therefore, I think we can't say "It's snowy" to talk about the weather. For that purpose, we should say "It's snowing". But we can talk about snowy mountains and snowy roads, which means mountains and roads that are covered with a lot of snow.

3. icy: Icy air or water is extremely cold and an icy road has ice on it.

Therefore, I think we can't say "It's icy" to talk about the weather. For that purpose, we can say "It's too/freezing cold". But we can describe the air as being icy.

However, unlike the above words, we can say "It's sunny/cloudy/foggy/ etc" to talk about the weather conditions.

Are my observations regarding these words correct?

Comment: We can say that it is or was icy, rainy, windy, foggy, snowy, or sunny on a particular day. It is rainy today here where I am.

Comment: As a native BrE speaker it's fine to say "it's icy"  or "the weather is icy". I would understand this to mean that that it was cold enough for water to freeze and that there were likely to be patches of ice around. I think you will find even the British TV weather presenters use phrases such as "icy conditions" meaning weather conditions in which you could expect ice to form [on roads and pavements].

Comment: "It will be rainy, windy and chilly today, with temperatures around 50 early today" Dayton (Ohio) Daily News, March 8 2022

Comment: If today is _rainy_, it may not actually be raining just at the moment. If today is _snowy_, there may be frequent snow showers or just snow on the ground.

Comment: As everyone is saying, no, your observations are not correct. It is perfectly idiomatic to say “it is rainy” to mean “it is raining” and vice versa, m.m., the same for snowy, icy, etc. It is not necessary for snow or ice to accumulate to use these descriptions for the weather. If you use them for an object, like a car, then yes, car must have snow or ice etc on it

Comment: Thanks everyone. Then is it possible that the problem lies with dictionaries for not refering to this usage?

Comment: @Mohsen Dictionaries do record such usages: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/rainy